# JNI.h jtypes and relations

Tags: types, jvm, java-native-interface

I saw the code of `jni.h` here :
 `http://xdprof.sourceforge.net/doxygen/jni_8h-source.html`

and i want to know what is this:

```
class _jobject {};
00053 class _jclass : public _jobject {};
00054 class _jthrowable : public _jobject {};
00055 class _jstring : public _jobject {};
00056 class _jarray : public _jobject {};
00057 class _jbooleanArray : public _jarray {};
00058 class _jbyteArray : public _jarray {};
00059 class _jcharArray : public _jarray {};
00060 class _jshortArray : public _jarray {};
00061 class _jintArray : public _jarray {};
00062 class _jlongArray : public _jarray {};
00063 class _jfloatArray : public _jarray {};
00064 class _jdoubleArray : public _jarray {};
00065 class _jobjectArray : public _jarray {};
```

What is the relation for example between `_jobject` empty class and `Object` class - "`Object.h/Object.cpp`" (internally in JVM) and why these classes are empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These classes are needed only to maintain hierarchy among corresponding JNI types:

```
jobject <- jarray <- jintArray etc.
```

So that `jarray` can be used, for example, in a function that accepts `jobject`.

The contents of the classes does not matter. JNI types are meant to be opaque for the application. There is no direct relation between JNI types and Java classes. This relation is hidden inside JVM code, i.e. if some JNI function expects `jstring` argument, JVM explicitly treats that argument as a handle to `java.lang.String` instance. E.g. from [HotSpot sources](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/0341fa6dbb36/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp#l3219):

```
JNI_QUICK_ENTRY(jsize, jni_GetStringLength(JNIEnv *env, jstring string))
  ...
  oop s = JNIHandles::resolve_non_null(string);
  if (java_lang_String::value(s) != NULL) {       <-- explicitly cast a handle
    ret = java_lang_String::length(s);
  }
```

The type safety of such operations may or may not be enforced in runtime depending on JVM implementation. E.g. HotSpot can simply crash if you pass some crafted `jstring` argument which is not actually a handle to `java.lang.String` object.

**EDIT**

`jstring` is a pointer to a pointer to a Java String instance (note double indirection). JVM does not access the value of `class _jstring` but rather treats it as a pointer to the actual instance (see the above example).

```
  java.lang.String             JNIHandleBlock                    jstring string
  ------------------           -----------------------           -----------------
 |  0: (header)     |<---\    | oop[0]                |     /---| class _jclass * |
 |  8: (class ptr)  |     \---| oop[1]  <------------------/     -----------------
 | 12: char[] value |         | ...                   |
 | 16: int hash     |         | oop[31]               |
 | 24: (padding)    |         |                       |
  ------------------          | int _top              |
                              | JNIHandleBlock* _next |
                              | ...                   |
                               -----------------------
```

When working with `jstring`, HotSpot JVM first resolves a handle to an `oop` (ordinary object pointer):

```
    oop s = JNIHandles::resolve_non_null(string);
    // This is effectively the same as
    //     oop s = *(oop*)string;
```

Then to read a field of an oop, JVM uses raw pointer arithmetic (assuming it knows that the field `value` has the offset 12 from the beginning of java.lang.String instance):

```
    java_lang_String::value(s)
    // Effectively the same as
    //     s->obj_field(12)
    // which is expanded to something like
    //     *(oop*)((intptr_t)s + 12)
```

Other JVM implementations may treat `class _jstring` differently. The idea is to make JNI types opaque so that different JVMs may implement JNI handles in their own way without need to recompile the code that uses those handles. That's why the contents of the classes does not matter - this is just the *declaration*, not the actual *definition* of the types.

Comment: What is the value of variable string?,    Class jstring is empty, so the variable is a jstring object with empty fields. So how JVM knows variable string what string-value contains ?

Comment: I don't think that this code  explicitly casts a JNI handle. First, it extracts an internal **Object** pointer from the handle (*resolve_non_null()*), and after that, the ** java_lang_String** methods use the **Object** pointer. Note that on HotSpot, **length()** is not a method of **String** class (which I would expect to be derived from **Object**), but rather a static method of **java_lang_String** class, and take an **Object** pointer as parameter.

Comment: @AlexCohn Depends on the meaning of "cast". What I mean is that JVM treats `s` as the pointer to an instance of `java.lang.String` and accesses String fields through this pointer. Semantically this is the same as static_cast.

Comment: @LeAdErQ I've updated the answer to explain this a bit more.

Comment: I can't understand how the type of "_jstring" is converted to "Object".  The function "jni_GetStringLength" takes as a parameter a _jstring object, but _jstring object is empty class. So how gets the real string ? In other words, when a native function calls the 'jni_GetStringLength' will give as parameter a _jstring object and no a string object. But _jstring object has not value - field  to "handle" the string-value and then the jni convert it to "Object" object without knowing what is the value of string.

Comment: @LeAdErQ Forget about `class _jstring`. You may think of `jstring` as of `void*` - a raw pointer to *something*. Only JVM knows what lies behind this *something*. Classes are needed only for the hierarchy of these pointers, so that compiler allows implicit convertion of `jstring` to `jobject` but not vice versa.

Comment: For the JVM this is just a pointer to the address of a real object. JVM reads raw data from the memory location referenced by this address.

Comment: Ok but how an object of _jstring class is a reference of other type of class without any "relation" between jstring and Object. If this happens , Should not the jstring keep the address of the actual object? (as a field)

Comment: @LeAdErQ Yes, jstring keeps the address of the actual object, but not as a field, but rather indirectly through one more level of referencing. I've added the illustration with comments to the answer.

Comment: The oop points to the real object string ? for example when we  create a new string, then JVM creates a new oop value in JNIHandleBlock or there is exists an specific unique oop for each java class? (string , etc.)

Comment: @LeAdErQ Yes, oop points to the real object. But there are no handles for it until JNI method is called. JNI handles (aka local JNI references) are allocated lazily at the time of a native call and then cleared on return from the call.

Comment: Wow! I understood ! THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

This may well vary across different runtime implementations, but I'll use Android's old Dalvik runtime as an example.

A `jobject`, which is defined as a `_jobject*`, is an *indirect reference*. Rather than being used as a normal pointer, the bits of the pointer are used to encode a reference type (local, global, weak global) and a reference table index ([source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik.git/+/kitkat-mr1-release/vm/IndirectRefTable.h#62)).

So when you pass a `jobject` to some JNI function, e.g. `NewGlobalRef`, that `jobject` will be passed on to [`dvmDecodeIndirectRef`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik.git/+/kitkat-mr1-release/vm/Jni.cpp#305), which determines the reference type, and returns the corresponding `Object*` from the appropriate reference table.

Answer (score 0):

JNI is not a C++ interface, it is a pure C interface. Luckily, JNI has a C++ wrapper, to reduce the boilerplate code when C++ compiler can help, and also avoid (some) mistakes where the C++ type system can reduce ambiguity.

Under the C++ hood that you posted, all JNI objects use black-box handles (you may call them object references) that are interpreted by the JNI functions. On Dalvik JVM, some of these handles were simply pointers into JVM internal tables, but this was an implementation detail that could only be relevant for some debugging.

This implementation detail caused significant troubles when switching to other JVMs, including the modern Android ART, because using pointers, we could sometimes get away with global references mixed with local references, etc.